# 'Alert Style' option missing from Notifications settings

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have set up an iOS app with push notifications.The problem is that the app ignores notifications while not being active or more precisely banners don't show up.One stranger thing is that the 'Alert Style' option is missing.

I wonder whether the .entitlements file is necessary and should I define something there.Except for that I think all settings are made correctly.
The environment is production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All push notification are handled by iOS not your app, iOS will deliver the push notification to your app after the user clicked/swiped the view option.

Did you set the correct type of notification, `UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert` for alerts(banners) when you register for notifications?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

More you can't set the 'Alert Style', the user can do this in settings app. You can't force the way  Notifications are presented.

Comment: This answer resolved the issue.Thank you, unfortunately I can't vote up.